# write an SQL statement for speed tracking

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have task to track speed of vehicles. I have database  with columns which consists of: `phoneid int, time timestamp, latitude double precision, longitude double precision,speed int`. These records are updated after every few seconds  I need an SQL statement which finds anyone with the average speed  between  50 to 100 mph for at least a minute .

The data is collected through GPS tracking logger.

Can anyone suggest me to find out  anyone whose average speed is exceeding the speed limit (i.e 50 to 100 mph) for at least a minute .

Should I first group records based on time or  should I group them with the average speed

If I write Select statement as:
  `select *,avg(speed) from Speed_track  group by phoneid;`
then I would be able fetch records based on speed only

Any other suggestions?

what analytical functions can I use?

Can I write proc for above?

Comment: How do you know they are not on a train?  Or in a 25 mph work zone?  How accurate is latitude and longitude?  What is the data type?  What if they are going downhill?

Comment: ... which country is this for again? Just curious... not like I have anything to be worried about...

Comment: This is probably data from the car sensors.

Comment: Have you looked at the geospatial extensions? Have you considered that calculating speed from lat/long is not reliable unless you have constant monitoring? Consider someone driving around a race track in 30 seconds - if you measure their speed every 30 seconds, they appear to stand still, even if they travel at 200 MpH

Comment: Is there a column called "speed" -- one part of your question does not mention it and another does.

Comment: Ohh yes there is a column speed

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: For a time interface t0 to t1, you are happy taking the average of all speed observations recorded during that interval as a representation of the average speed during the interval. If the speed observations come in irregularly, this may not be a good assumption and it complicates your problem.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT phoneid, 
    time, 
    (SELECT AVG(speed) FROM Speed_Track STI 
        WHERE STI.phoneid = STO.phoneid AND
           STI.time > TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, -1, STO.time)
           AND STI.TIME <= STO.time) as minute_rolling_avg
 FROM Speed_Track STO) POSSIBLE_SPEEDERS
 WHERE POSSIBLE_SPEEDERS.minute_rolling_avg > 50.0 
     AND POSSIBLE_SPEEDERS.minute_rolling_avg <= 100
```

This is kind of brute force. Maybe there is another way. I would be tempted to find a way to eliminate every phone that NEVER went above 50 to save having to calculate moving averages for them.